# why android chrome replace refferer?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, install-referrer

i need to redirect the user from chrome to google play to download my android applications. so i run this code in the web page which is opened by chrome :

```
window.location=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mypackageName.comf&referrer=utm_source%3DtestSource512%26utm_medium%3DtestMedium512%26anid%3Dadmob
```

I don't know why the chrome replace the referrer with :`com.android.chrome`

is it possible to prevent the chrome from replacing the referrer and just use the given referrer.

thanks

Comment: Its their servers.  I don't think you can override it.  Perhaps you have it setup wrong?

Comment: but chrome override my referrer value when he direct the user to google play. it's my server

Comment: Chrome does not change the referrer. It happens only when there is no exsting referrer. What I understand is the referrer you are providing is not being recognized. Check my other answer below. I also see typo at
..id=mypackageName.comf&referrer...   I see an extraf after com, probably that is causing the problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746583/google-play-store-is-changing-the-referrer-data-to-com-android-chrome